# How to get all values from a list?

Tags: javascript, jsp

Sorry in advance, dev code and web access are on two seperate platforms so I could not copy and paste.

In my jsp if have a list define as such:

```
<form:form id=""fm-form commandname="command" action="$actionURL" onsubmit="return false;">
// what does this commandName="command" do?  I see it in several places in the code
// and it all has to do with dropdown lists.
.
.
.
.
.
<form:select id="fm-explosives2" path="fm-explosives2" items="${command.explosiveList}"       onchange="populateDensity(); populatetntEquiv()";/>
```

Then I make a call to the makeCaluculations() in .js file...

```
function makeCalculations(){
...
var explosiveNames = new array();
.
.
.
var explosiveList = DWRUtil.getValue("fm-explosive2"); 
// this should have all the names from the dropdown list - or am I wrong?

// then I try to populate the array to be used later...
for (var i=0; i < explosiveList.length; i++){
      var explosive = explosiveList[i];

      alert("explosive name is: " + explosive.explosives);  // all NULL values!!! Why? Help!
      explosiveNames.push(explosive.explosives);
      more code .....

}
```

}

Question:  what does this commandName="command" (in the .jsp source) do?  I see it in several places in the code
           and it all has to do with dropdown lists. Anyone?

Comment: `explosivenames.explosives` or just `explosiveList[i].explosives` instead of `explosive.explosives` ??? Couldn't you use less confusing variables names, hard to figure out what is what here. Your code is quite unreadable

Comment: I know I just inherited this code, it is a mess. Plus I am new to js/jsp/jquery/dwr.

Comment: @MichealNoel well renaming local variables is not that hard

Comment: Will do, but can you see why the values from the expliveList as defined in the jsp is returning null values? On the web page there are over 45 values in the list so should the DWRUtil.getValue() call give me those values?

Comment: @Anton. Sorry var explosivenames = explosiveList[i];           Should be var explosive = explosiveList[i];

Comment: @MichealNoel You should update your question to what it should be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `explosive`  is not defined in your entire code.
2. in the loop, it shouln't be `explosive.explosives`, it should be `explosiveList[i].explosives`, where `explosives` can be your entity of the `explosiveList[i]`

> So, basically replace all `explosive.explosives` with
>   `explosiveList[i].explosives` in your code, then it should work.

Comment: Just tried that and all the explosiveList[i].explosives in the alert were undefined.

Comment: then do _alert(explosiveList[i])_, and see what is this. If _explosives_ is avalaible there, then alert it.

Comment: Ok. That almost worked. So each item in the list looks like this: "2, 4 Tnt xxxxx", the alert statement is giving me each character in the name. Not each complete name. So explosiveList[0]) = 2, explosiveList[1])=, explosiveList[2])=4 etc....

Comment: well, can you give me all the alerts here... at leat 2-3 of them?

Comment: also, check _typeof explosiveList[i]_

Comment: The alerts are: explosiveList[0] = "2", explosiveList[1] = ",", explosiveList[0] = "4". when I ran it again, I got the the selected explosive from the webpage, but my team here at work says I am supposed to a get a list of all the explosives in the list. Doesn't make any sense to me, but that is what I am told. Also, what does this [commandName="command"] (in the .jsp source) do?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment clarification. Your function should look something like...

```
function makeCalculations(){
var explosiveNames = [];
var explosives = DWRUtil.getValue("fm-explosive2"); 
// this should have all the names from the dropdown list - or am I wrong?

// then I try to populate the array to be used later...
for (var i=0; i < explosives.length; i++){
      var explosivenames = explosiveList[i];

      alert("explosive name is: " + explosives[i].explosives);
      explosiveNames.push(explosives[i].explosives);
}
```

Comment: Sorry var explosivenames = explosiveList[i]; Should be var explosive = explosiveList[i];

Comment: Nope. Didnt work. alert("explosive name is: " + explosives[i].explosives);
Values : undefined.

Comment: The explosives come from a table and the list is populated at startup.